# Restrict Cash on delivery based on Country under shipping method

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, cash-on-delivery, countries

I want to restrict COD based on country we select under billing address in checkout page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to allow the COD payment method for only specified countries:

1. Go to system -> configuration -> **Payment Methods**
2. Expand the section **"Cash on Delivery Payment**
3. Change **"Payment from Applicable Countries"** to "Specific countries."
4. In the **Payment from Specific Countries** list, select only the countries where you want Cash on Delivery to appear. (Tip: hold down the CMD key to select multiple countries.)
5. Save the configuration.

[image]